# Id not coming in dropdown using viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I am trying to get dropdown list in my application, Well name of my dropdown is coming  but i can't track id of user with it.

I tried doing it this way-

**Controller-**

```
 public ActionResult _Dropdown()
        {
            var list = (from u in db.Users
                        select new { u.Name, u.Id }).ToList();
            ViewBag.uName = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Name");
            return PartialView();
        }
```

**Method-**

```
@model registration.User

@Html.DropDownList("Name", new SelectList(ViewBag.uName, "Id", "Name"))
```

I am getting "Id" is not found error and when replacing it with name same as for name also.

How do I resolve this issue?

**Note-**

I will only populate names and Id should be of selected item. I can't attach Id with this dropdown list.

Comment: should it be `@Html.DropDownList("Name", ViewBag.uName)`?

Comment: @simoco, It will only populate names. I want to get selected item's Id with it.

Comment: try for this : @Html.DropDownList("Name", (SelectList)ViewBag.uName)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ViewBag.uName = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Name");
```

and in view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.yourModel, (SelectList)ViewBag.uName, "--select--")
```